# How to disable the [HP] ACPI button for the wireless card?

Tags: wireless, 14.04, 64-bit, acpi

I have Ubuntu 14.04 running on a Compaq CQ60 laptop. Ever since I installed Ubuntu (back on 12.04), the "toggle wireless" button next to the power button hard locks the WiFi adapter, causing me to have to run the `sudo rfkill unlock wifi` command in Terminal.

Issue is, other people use the computer and press the button by accident when I'm not around to fix it, causing the laptop to be (basically) useless. I'm looking for a way to change the button's action or disable it entirely. I've seen a lot of questions on here having to do with the power button, but not the wireless toggle button.

About all I know about it is it's a ACPI button and it worked properly when Windows ran on the computer. (Ew) Does anyone know how to change its' ACPI action and/or where its' ACPI action script is located on the filesystem?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Is the module _hp-wmi_ loaded? check from the terminal: lsmod Is the behavior improved if you remove the module entirely? sudo modprobe -r hp-wmi If so, we can simply blacklist it.

Comment: The module appears to be called `hp_wmi`. When I ran that command, suddenly the button works as it should. If you press it again, it will re-enable the WiFi as expected. But for future reference, why don't you post that and how to disable it entirely as an answer to this question.

Answer (score 3):

Now that we know that the module `hp_wmi` is blocking the wireless, let's blacklist it. From the terminal:

```
echo "blacklist hp_wmi" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-hp.conf
```

Reboot and you should be all set.

Comment: Sadly, that didn't disable the button entirely. Do I need to undo the `sudo modprobe -r hp_wmi` command I ran earlier to make it work? (Would I replace the `-r` with an `-a`?

Comment: To reload the module, simply do: sudo modprobe hp-wmi. Can you confirm that if it is blacklisted, the behavior is _not_ correct, but if removed after boot; i.e. modprobe -r, the behavior _is_ correct?

Comment: The blacklist doesn't change anything. `modprobe -r` makes it the behavior correct, but blacklisting it after that does nothing.

Comment: The blacklist only blocks the module on boot. Are you confirming that on fresh boot, with the blacklist in place, the behavior is _incorrect_?

Comment: By behavior, I assume you mean the LED color of the button. Blacklist, or no blacklist, the behavior is *correct*, but the button isn't *disabled*. Does that make sense?

Comment: If the behavior of the button is _correct_; i.e. it turns the wireless on and off as expected, then we are all done here, yes?

Comment: We could be. I was also wondering how you could *disable* the button all together. Are you up for that?

Comment: Aside from a screwdriver, I know of no method to do so.

Comment: @David Foerster `hp-wmi` and `hp_wmi` are the same. Verify with `modinfo hp-wmi` and `modinfo hp_wmi` Your blacklist-hp.conf is no more effective nor ineffective that simply blacklist.conf.

Comment: @chili555: I didn't know about that module name alias. Good to know! Still parts files are easier to manage than having it all inside a single file.